# Powershell post request does not react to parameters

Tags: powershell, post, httpwebrequest

Right now I'm trying to build a dictionary attack tool for hackthebox.eu. I'm using PowerShell to send POST requests to the test website, but it is ignoring the parameters sent. If I send them with Firefox, everything works fine.

My request: `$request = Invoke-Webrequest -Uri http://88.198.233.174:34426/ -Method post -body "passwort=dummypass";`

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Change `"passwort=dummypass"` to `@{passwort="dummypass"}`

Comment: It still only responds with the body of the default website, not the one with "wrong credentials" in the first line.

Comment: should passwort be password?

Comment: such a silly error, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

try using the -UseBasicParsing switch.